# material table datasource from firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material, angularfire2

Hi I am using angular material 5 and angular 5 along with angularFirebase2 version 5.
I am able to get the datasource and display the material table, but when i am trying to pull the data from the firebase list its not displaying data in the table.

inside my component:

```ts
public result;

dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.result);

constructor(private db : AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.result = this.db.list('sellEntries').valueChanges();
}
```

```html
 <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
            <div class="search-bar">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
                </mat-form-field>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="applyFilter('')">All</button>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="applyFilter('india')">India</button>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="applyFilter('south africa')">South Africa</button>
            </div>
                <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">



                    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>


                    <ng-container matColumnDef="material">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.material}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>


                    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
                        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
                        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.country}} </mat-cell>
                    </ng-container>

                    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                </mat-table>
            </div>
```

The table is working and loading data properly if I use component binding. I am looking for a way to load the data source from the Firebase Realtime Database. Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of mutating the dataSource, did you try creating it with the actual observable in constructor or ngOnInit? this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.db.list('sellEntries').valueChanges());

Comment: @funkizer , i think that wont work, as MatTableDataSource is expecting a array as a parameter, while valueChanges() returns a observable.

Comment: Aoki, i thought it can take an observable as well since op didn't mention an IDE warning or anything, bad IDE if it doesn't warn about that. :) I always use a custom DS extending TableDataSource, in the connect -method just return the observable.

Comment: Ah not a bad IDE, bad IDE user. You should've typed `result` as Observable, then you'd probably get a warning and a build error. Always type things! Typescript helps you catch these kind of bugs really easily :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, MatTableDataSource's constructor is expecting an array. You should always type variables so your IDE and the build process will let you know about fumblings of this sort. Two ways to go, a) extend the DataSource class:

```
class MyDataSource<T> extends DataSource<T> {
    constructor(private observable: Observable<T[]>) {}
    connect() {
        return this.observable;
    }
}
// Component: 
dataSource: MyDataSource<any>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MyDataSource(this.db.list('sellEntries').valueChanges());
}
```

b) Subscribe and manually set the data:

```
destroy$:Subject<void> = new Subject();
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
    this.db.list('sellEntries').valueChanges().pipe(
        takeUntil(destroy$); // Complete & cleanup
    ).subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data);
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
}
```

Personally, I'd go with a) as the class is reusable and makes components leaner.

Comment: thanks, its working now, i forgot to update the html part and bind the correct keys in mat-row. with above solutions its working fine. thanks.

Comment: np, glad to hear :)